# nginx change basepath html folder to another disk ubuntu 18.4

Tags: nginx-location, ubuntu-18.04

Hello I'm new to ubuntu 18.4
I want to change html folder from

```
/var/www/html
```

to another directory usually at ubuntu 16.4 i used to change basepath at

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

to the location but the new location is at another partition so i used to put it like that

```
/mnt/7282B48E0BE626E0/www/html
```

but now i don't know how to change it to the same directory because of mnt folder empty and when i put

```
/dev/sda7/www/html
```

it doesn't work too any help
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the main problem was that i'm unable to put the directory with user name at nginx config so i mount partition inside mnt folder here what I did
i created folder name "7282B48E0BE626E0"

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/7282B48E0BE626E0
```

and mount it with sda7

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/7282B48E0BE626E0
```

its working now.